# write raw binary to file in C

Tags: c, binary

I am trying to write raw binary bits at a time to a file.

I have found an example that uses unsigned char ->https://stackoverflow.com/a/2666669/1541965

But the minimum size is 8 bit (because of the unsigned char 0 to 255).

Is there a way to write bits to a file in a more direct way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't said what operating system you're using. But generally the smallest unit you get to write to a file is one 8-bit byte. If you want to write individual bits, you'll need to assemble them into bytes in your own code. I don't know of any OS whose file IO facilities allow writing of individual bits.

Comment: RAM and disks can't even *store* individual bits.  The smallest addressable unit on any non-esoteric computer is an 8-bit byte.

Comment: The *real* smallest addressable unit in modern RAM hardware is 64 bits; for discs it's generally 512 or 4096 bytes. It just happens that the CPU conveniently lets you pretend that the RAM is accessible bytewise, and the OS lets you pretend that the disc is accessible bytewise. So it's not really any more true that RAM and discs can't store individual bits than that they can't store individual bytes. :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't, at least not directly. C's I/O model for binary files is that they're sequences of bytes (typically 8 bits).

What you can do is, in your own code, write a function that takes a 1-bit value and gathers the bits into a byte, writing them to the file when it's received 8 bits. You'll also need to do an additional write at the end if the byte value hasn't been filed yet.

It's not possible to write a partial byte; you can, if necessary, pad the last byte with zeros if necessary.

(The C standard requires a byte to be *at least* 8 bits, but it permits it to be more. The number of bits in a byte is specified by `CHAR_BIT`, defined in `<limits.h>`. `CHAR_BIT` is going to be exactly 8 on any system you're likely to encounter.)